# SQL group and sum

Tags: sql-server

So I can't seem to find an answer to this specifically

In our ordering system a client wants to get a report that shows a product and the quantity ordered per month

The report columns would look like below

Item, January, February, March

under each month would be the total quantity ordered for that month

Below is my current code just to show orders for January

```
SELECT
[Order].Date
, CONVERT(CHAR(12), DATENAME(MONTH, [Order].Date)) as 'Month'
, ISNULL([order].TotalQuantity, [order].UnitQtysQtyPerUnit*[order].Quantity) as 'Quantity'
, [Order].Productname as 'Product'
FROM [Order] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CartTransaction ON CartTransaction.CartTransaction_Id = [Order].CartTransaction_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer ON Customer.Customer_Id = [Order].Customer_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN CostCentre ON CostCentre.CostCentre_Id = [Order].CostCentre_Id
where CustomerName = 'Customer A' and [Order].Date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are generating a report, you should probably let the reporting layer handle the pivot, but you could send the data as aggregated by `month` like so:

```
select
    dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Order].Date ), 0) as 'MonthDate'
  , convert(char(12),datename(month, [Order].Date)) as 'Month'
  , sum(isnull([order].TotalQuantity, [order].UnitQtysQtyPerUnit*[order].Quantity)) as 'Quantity'
  , [Order].Productname as 'Product'
from [Order] 
  left outer join CartTransaction
    on CartTransaction.CartTransaction_Id = [Order].CartTransaction_Id
  left outer join Customer
    on Customer.Customer_Id = [Order].Customer_Id
  left outer join CostCentre
    on CostCentre.CostCentre_Id = [Order].CostCentre_Id
where CustomerName = 'Customer A' 
  and [Order].Date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31'
group by 
    dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Order].Date ), 0)
  , convert(char(12),datename(month, [Order].Date))
  , [Order].ProductName
order by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Order].Date ), 0)
```

Comment: thank you! This did the trick for grouping the product and quantity together.

Comment: Is there a way you know of that I could order this by date without it showing on the report itself?

Comment: `order by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Order].Date ), 0)`

Comment: Awesome thanks again! I don't have a high enough rep to mark as the answer but it is if anyone can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't assume that we are familiar with the data structure, please provide more information on the question.

What you most probably missing is grouping. You have to group by Item and Date and get the Calculated TotalSum of totalQuantity per month.

Sketch:

```
Select o.ProductName, o.Date, Sum(o.TotalQuantity) as Quantity
From order o, Carttrans ct, customer c, costCent cc
where o.cartTransaction_id = ct.CartTransaction_id
and c.customer_id = o.customer_id
And cs.costcentre_id = o.costcentre_id
And customerName = '...'
and o.Date between ....
Group by o.ProductName and o.Date
```

Comment: Why would take the joins that the OP posted in ANSI-92 style and convert them to the antiquated ANSI-89 style joins? https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins